# Why pages not made young is zero?

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.5

In results of `Show INNODB Status` showed me very weird result:

```
Pages made young 81821279, not young 0
```

The official statement says:

[**Pages made young, not young:** The number of old pages that were moved to the head of the buffer pool (the new sublist), and the number of pages that have remained in the old sublist without being made new.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html)

What I get from this is that there were zero pages that sustained in pool or in other words my pool size is too small to sustain pages.

Am I correct? If not what does it mean then?

Should I be increasing buffer pool size? And is there any other ways to resolve this because my buffer pool size is already 80% of my RAM.

Comment: How much RAM does the DB Server have ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: 16GB